# Java Sockets - Messages between many clients

Tags: java, sockets, ipc

So the problem is I have fifteen clients which need to be able to communicate between each other. My question is how should this be done? Clearly one way is to simply make the clients also servers, but  that means 120 unique connections necessary to fully connect the fifteen clients. I'd rather not do this as it seems messy.

Current solution:
Each new connection has the server spin off a separate thread for listening to it. Each client has a separate thread monitoring the channel for incoming information.

Server acts as a message router: Process 1 needs to send a message to Process 2 and sends a message to the server indicating intended recipient, sender, and message.

Upon receiving the message the server passes message to Process 2. The listening thread detects it and passes it to the process.

So on for each message between the clients.

This seems clunky. Is there a better methodology/package to use for this?

Comment: You could look at the java.nio package introduced with Java 7. It offers non-blocking socket channels to better handle your type of scenario. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html

Comment: Take a look at UDP / [DatagramSocket](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html). There is no confirmation, that your data arrived, like when using TCP / `Socket`, but it allows all servers to send recive stuff, to whoever they want to.

Comment: You might want to explore a Peer-to-Peer approach!

Comment: Think about your requirements.  Do clients come and go?  Do you need deferred messages to be sent when a client comes back?  etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A UDP multicast system would work for this but will get complicated for you to do yourself (since you have to worry about synchronization and fault detection/correction yourself as well as nodes droping in and out of the group).

There are various middleware solutions including distributed caches that already address this problem pretty well.  Look at Infinispan.  If that's too high level and you just want a lower level solution, try JGroups.  I only list those because I know they are quick and usable, but there are many others out there.

Comment: Infinispan is a bit too high level, and more powerful than I really need. JGroups seems to be the best. Thank you, very solid answer.